# One Sheeted Hyperboloid

Tags: quadratic-forms

Putting this into Wolfram Alpha, I saw that it is a one-sheeted hyperboloid:

$$2x^2 - 4xz + z^2 - 4yz = 4$$

Would someone be able to explain how to prove this mathematically? I thought this surface had to be of the form:

$$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$$

I have a feeling it has to do with eigenvalues but I can't quite figure it out...

Comment: The first expression can be rewrited as the second one just doin some resonable rotation.

Comment: rotation? what do you mean by this?

Comment: Pick a matrix $A\in O(3)$ and apply $x,y,z$ on it.

Comment: I'm still confused... what do you mean by apply x,y,z on it?

Comment: I mean multiply the matrix $A$ with each vector $x=(1,0,0),y=(0,1,0),z=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: what is the matrix A?

Comment: A rotation matrix.

Comment: You have the sign wrong, you typed an ellipsoid as your example surface... $$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$$ has one sheet, but $$x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = -1$$ has two sheets.

Comment: oops! my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use quadratic forms techniques from linear algebra. See [here](http://calvino.polito.it/~salamon/P/L/lag21.pdf).

Comment: @AndrejRadonjić: You are welcome.